# Android jetpack compose NoSuchMethodError: No static method setContent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**Jetpack Compose release version: 1.0.0-alpha06
Android Studio Build:
4.2 1Canery 15**

**my Activity**

```
class MainActivityA : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
              Text(text = "hello", modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp))
        }

    }
```

THe above when run compiles this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setContent$default(Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Recomposer;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;ILjava/lang/Object;)Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composition; in class Landroidx/compose/ui/platform/WrapperKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrapperKt' appears in /data/app/com.jonathan-_j03c44RbBo00Hn7DeOjeA==/base.apk)
```

some of my gradle settings

def jetpack_compose = "1.0.0-alpha06"

```
 kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.0'
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "$jetpack_compose"
    }

  //JetPack Compose stuff
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$jetpack_compose"
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$jetpack_compose"
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$jetpack_compose"
    // Material Design
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$jetpack_compose"
    // Material design icons
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$jetpack_compose"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$jetpack_compose"
    // Integration with observables
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$jetpack_compose"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:$jetpack_compose"
```

Top level build script

```
/ Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-alpha15"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. It worked for me after adding the following line in the app Gradle file

```
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
```

Comment: this is already present, still getting the crash

Answer (score 7):

If you are in a multi module setup make sure you have this configuration added in your module gradle file insided the android block where you have compose dependencies.

the below is code syntax for KTS but it should be easily translatable in groovy too

```
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "$Version_Number"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove androidx.navigation:navigation-compose dependency as well, that was the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with the default Wear OS project from Android Sudio, upgrading all the dependencies in `gradle(:app)` fixed the issue.